# Keras reshape from (None,None,None,512) to (None,None,None,None,512)?

Tags: python, image, keras, neural-network

I am trying to reshape a 4D tensor to a 5D tensor, but Reshape doesn't accept None Values (I tried replacing it with -1 but it also didn't work] any idea how can I achieve that? is it even possible to achieve that?

I tried:

```
x=Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

new_dims=(1,-1,-1,512)

res=Reshape(target_shape=new_dims)(x)
```

Comment: Can you please add more context as to what you're trying to achieve? Also, have you looked at the examples in the documentation? https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape When you use '-1' for a dimension, the shape is automatically inferred. Also, batch axis need not be specified for target shape.

Comment: @ManojMohan k:0/device:GPU:0", but when I tried -1 as I wrote above I got this error send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_3691_loss/add", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]] 2019-03-11 14:13:46.806892: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at reshape_op.h:51 : Invalid argument: Only one input size may be -1, not both 2 and 3 Exception: Only one input size may be -1, not both 2 and 3

Comment: If one of the dimensions is -1, it can be inferred, but if more than one dimension has -1, then of course there are multiple solutions and hence you see the error.

Comment: then what should I do? can you please advice me I feel that I reached a dead end to convert it to a 5D tensor

Comment: I added an answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tailor the values in Reshape to the size needed.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Reshape
from keras.models import Model

input = Input((224,224,3))
x = Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input)
output = Reshape((2, 112, 224, 512))(x)
model = Model(input, output)
print(model.summary())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but Reshape_1 is a 5D tensor yes but the 3rd and 4th value are 112 and 224 and my model outputs different number since my input=Input(None,None,3) but  in this case 112 and 224 won't match my input.

Comment: Without more details regarding the problem it is difficult to help.